# convert value to simple notation from scientific notation in java

Tags: java, primitive-types

When my double value exceed from 7 digits it's show value in scientific notation. But, i don't want scientific notation.

DecimalFormat is one way to do the same but, for that i require to convert value into string.
is it possible the same conversion without converting double to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DecimalFormat.format(Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) can handle a `double` without any String involvement.

Comment: I will check it again that DecimalFormat.format() method's return type is string

Comment: Uhm, the representation in scientific notation is of course always a `String` because you only need it when displaying the value. The internal calculation does not know anything of notation, and it doesn’t care.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying it, it is a String.

By using DecimalFormat, you are just telling Java how to do the conversion

Without this, it will use the default scientific notation

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 123456789.4335;
System.out.println(">> "+new DecimalFormat("#0.###").format(d));
System.out.println(">> "+d);
```

prints

```
 >> 123456789.434
 >> 1.234567894335E8
```